# How to solve "Could not open Postman error " on linux/fedora

Tags: postman, postman-native-app

After successfully downloading and using Postman desktop app for several months I started observing that Postman used to consume almost two-three minutes before rendering the expected Editor.
There are times when I did observe the "Could not open Postman error " consistently.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the below steps to get rid of this : (I hope you have synced all your earlier data with any of your user account in  the past.)

1. Let's still ensure if any Postman Process is being running in the
   background : pidof Postman  If yes, kill them using  killall Postman
2. Locate the .config/Postman directory in your system :
   ~/.config/Postman
3. Navigate to this path and remove the entire
   Postman folder.

Click on your Downloaded Postman agent and follow the login process and things shall work well.